# Fix RestError Bot Framework

Tags: botframework

How do I fix this problem. Been lately receiving this causing my bot to be unresponsive.

[image]

I use node v8.11.2 and bot framework sdk v4 botbuilder version 4.8.0.

Thank you!

UPDATE:
when I add console.error(error) this shows up:

```
code: undefined,statusCode: 401,request:WebResource {streamResponseBody: false,url:'https://facebook.botframework.com/v3/conversations/2073757266064270-1820074761374022/activities/IaVk3v72Rl1',method: 'POST',headers: HttpHeaders { _headersMap: [Object] },body:'{"type":"typing","serviceUrl":"https://facebook.botframework.com/","channelId":"facebook","from":{"id":"1820074761374022"},"conversation":{"id":"2073757266064270-1820074761374022"},"recipient":{"id":"2073757266064270"},"replyToId":"IaVk3v72Rl1"}',query: undefined,formData: undefined,withCredentials: false,abortSignal: undefined,timeout: 0,onUploadProgress: undefined,onDownloadProgress: undefined,operationSpec:{ httpMethod: 'POST',path: 'v3/conversations/{conversationId}/activities/{activityId}',urlParameters: [Array],requestBody: [Object],responses: [Object],serializer: [Serializer] } },response:{ body: '',headers: HttpHeaders { _headersMap: [Object] },status: 401 },body: undefined }
```

ERROR in my other bot:

[onTurnError] unhandled error: Error
(node:11104) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: BotFrameworkAdapter.processActivity(): 500 ERRORErrorat new RestError (D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules@azure\ms-rest-js\dist\msRest.node.js:1397:28)at D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules@azure\ms-rest-js\dist\msRest.node.js:1849:37at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)at BotFrameworkAdapter. (D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\botbuilder\lib\botFrameworkAdapter.js:638:27)
at Generator.throw ()at rejected (D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\botbuilder\lib\botFrameworkAdapter.js:13:65)at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)(node:11104) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 15)

Comment: What steps can reproduce this error? Does it only happen in a particular situation? In `index.js`, in the `onTurnErrorHandler`, please add `console.error(error)` so that we can get the full stack trace. If you can provide your appId and/or bot name, I can look up things on the back end.

Comment: thank you @mdrichardson! I updated the question above and you can see what it shows when I put ```console.error(error)```. Can I personally message you about appId/bot name?

Comment: I was able to get the information I needed from your conversationId. Can you try removing the Facebook channel from your bot, then re-adding it? It looks like it needs to be re-authenticated: `Error validating access token: The user has not authorized application 2219050101643998.` [See here for instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-channel-connect-facebook?view=azure-bot-service-4.0)

Comment: OMG it fixed the problem! Thank you so much @mdrichardson !

So, in the future when this thing happens again, I'll just delete and reestablish my bot fb channel. noted with so many thanks!

Comment: Good to hear! I've added this as an answer, now that we've found it. Glad it worked!

Comment: hi @mdrichardson, I have a different bot, my test bot, and I thought the problem was the same (as before it was RestError) but now that I used ```console.log(error)``` it showed different. I tried to delete and reconnect but the error persists. How do I resolve this one? Kindly see error in my other bot section in the question. Thanks!

Comment: 500s could be a lot of issues. What steps do you take to reproduce it? And be sure to use `console.error(error)`, not `console.log(error)`

Comment: hello @mdrichardson, oddly, today the bot now works fine. I really didn't change anything except adding ```console.error(error)``` any advise that I could do once this thing occur again?

Comment: Nothing specific. Just copy/paste the entire error and stack trace into a new StackOverflow post, along with steps to reproduce it and appId, and we can usually find the fix pretty quick.

Comment: Since my answer fixed your first issue,  please "accept" and upvote it so others can quickly find the answer and I can clear this from my support tracker. If not, let me know how else I can help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can happen if your Facebook token expires. Unfortunately, we don't have a way to refresh it, ourselves. To fix it, delete the Facebook channel, then re-add it following [these instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-channel-connect-facebook?view=azure-bot-service-4.0).

Comment: I am facing the same error but with Directline channel. and when i restart the service it's working fine.